# MySQL - How to select all results from a table based on the relation between two different tables?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: **Inquery**, **Operator** and **Operator_Region**.

[image: tables]

The data entered in the tables are as follows:
[image]

Each operator can have one or more regions. I need to display all the results of the **INQUIRY** table that have the **Region** field equal to the logged-in user's(**Operator**)  Operator_Region.regionName field. see the image below:

[image: sql select result]

I'm trying as follow:

```
SELECT region FROM `INQUIRY`
INNER JOIN `OPERATOR` on `INQUIRY`.`region` WHERE `INQUIRY`.`region` IN (

SELECT
    regionName
FROM
    `OperatorRegion`
INNER JOIN `Operator` ON `OperatorRegion`.`OperatorID` = operatorID
WHERE
    operatorRegion.operatorID = 2)
```

I need that the query to return only the INQUIRY table rows that match to the **logged in** operator's region (in this case is Alisson). The operator regions are in the "operator region_table".

But returning empty. This is my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc5cee/2)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I do not know if I get it. But I edited the question, =)

Comment: You're not getting it, but I don't know why. It's three simple steps!?!

Comment: I updated the question with a SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inquiry;

CREATE TABLE inquiry
(inquiry_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,region VARCHAR(12) 
);

INSERT INTO inquiry VALUES
(1,'Hawaii'),
(2,'Hawaii'),
(3,'Paris'),
(4,'New York');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS operator;

CREATE TABLE operator 
(operator_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,operator_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO operator VALUES
(101,'John'),
(102,'Alisson'),
(103,'Peter');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS operator_region;

CREATE TABLE operator_region 
(operator_id INT NOT NULL
,region VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (operator_id,region)
);

INSERT INTO operator_region (operator_id,region) 
VALUES (102,'New York'),
       (102,'Los Angeles'),
       (102,'Hawaii'),
       (101,'New York'),
       (103,'Paris');


SELECT i.* 
  FROM inquiry i 
  JOIN operator_region ro 
    ON ro.region = i.region 
  JOIN operator o 
    ON o.operator_id = ro.operator_id 
 WHERE o.operator_name = 'Alisson';
+------------+----------+
| inquiry_id | region   |
+------------+----------+
|          1 | Hawaii   |
|          2 | Hawaii   |
|          4 | New York |
+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed. A hug. =)